# weak derivative, Sobolev spaces and boundary conditions

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem, weak-derivatives

I have 2 questions on 2 subsequent pages in a [book](http://62.182.86.140/main/857000/96727826294444c8132e5ca6d90bc36e/%28Graduate%20Studies%20in%20Mathematics%29%20Lawrence%20C.%20Evans%20-%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations_%20Second%20Edition%20-AMS%20%282010%29.djvu) on PDE, so I'll post them as a one question.

The first is formula (1) in the firs snippet, namely what is $u_{x_i}$ there and how we have obtained by integration by parts this formula (1), most importantly the $-$ term in front of $-\int$.

The second question is on the following snippet above **Example 2** and word "as required": I think that there should be $\psi(2)-\psi(1)$ and not $\psi(1)-\psi(1)$.
Anyway, I do not follow all the three equalities following the words "But we easily calculate". There seem to be some typos in bounds which I'm unable to correct.
Can someone kindly help me ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. The multidimensionnal integration by parts formula comes from the divergence theorem, applied to $u\phi \: e_i$:
   $$\int_U u_{x_i}\phi + u\phi_{x_i} = \int (u\phi)_{x_i} = \int_U div(u\phi \: e_i) = \int_{\partial U} u\phi \: e_i \cdot dn$$
   Because $\phi \in C^\infty_c(U)$, $\phi$ is zero on the boundary $\partial U$, so we have:
   $$\int_U u_{x_i}\phi + u\phi_{x_i} = =0$$
2. Since $\phi$ vanishes on the boundary of $U$, there is no $\phi(2)$ term for the second integral. The $+\phi(1)$ term comes from the integration by parts of $\int_0^1 x \phi'$, it is the boundary term.

Comment: It’s annoying when people downvote an answer without explaining what they think is wrong. Anyway, I think that your answer is correct. Welcome to math stack exchange.